# Keep merged cells across 2 Synced Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

So, on Google Sheets, Im trying to reference merged cells across 2 sheets.
1 Sheet has merged cells (ie. `A2:A7`) but when I reference it on the second sheet, they unmerge and the data is only shown in `A2`.

Is there a way to keep the cells merged when copying over? I don't want to have to remerge all the new cells as I input data.

It's employee time sheets and the merged cells are their work expenses across an entire day but the cells (`A2:A7`) show for example, 5 jobs across the day so I want it to show 1 cell of expenses for the whole day of work (5 rows).

Answer (score 0):

> when I reference it on the second sheet, they unmerge and the data is only shown in A2.

That is because there are no other values in any member cells of that merged cell.  The only member cell with data is A2   <sub><sup>**>>** See **Merged Cells** below</sup></sub>

> Is there a way to keep the cells merged when copying over?

Copying the merged cell to another location *will* maintain the merged cell.  Referencing a member cell of the merged cell will not

### References Return Values not Formats

Merging cells is a formatting option found under the "Format" menu.  When referencing merged cells (much like cell references to any normal cells or range of cells) the *"values"* are returned, not the formatting.

If you want to copy formatting from one place to another within a sheet or across sheets, simply use the "Paint format" tool, or copy the merged cells and then use the "Format only" option under "Paste special" <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

### Merged Cells

1. The only cell that can be edited in a merged cell is the one in the top-leftmost position.  The rest of the cells are completely BLANK
2. If you have a range of cells and you merge them, only the top-leftmost value will be retained, it will stay (or be moved) to the top-leftmost cell, and the rest of the values will be wiped.
3. If you unmerge a range of cells your original values will be lost.
4. You can reference any member of a merged cell as you would normally.  All but the top leftmost cell will always be empty.  If you want to reference a value in a merged cell, you would simply reference the top-leftmost cell address.

In this example GIF, `A1:D4` is first merged and then unmerged.  The version of the range after it is unmerged matches the layout of the merged cell, and the referencing would be identical.  The original layout and contents were wiped never to reappear in merged or unmerged form.
<sub>**Merging then un-merging a range of cells**</sub>
[image]